# Antlr single child tree using rewrite rules

Tags: antlr, binary-tree

I have this formula:

**negationExpr
        : NEGATION^* atom
        ;**

**atom

       : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';**

With grammer rules above, if I input formula ¬¬a, I would get this tree structure:

¬ being the root node,
¬ being left child; a being right child

However, What I would like to have is:
¬ being the root node,
second ¬ being the only child of the above node
a being the only child of the second ¬

Basically, I wat all the NEGATION sign have only have one child, it is possible? I know we could probabely use "rewrite rule" to restructure the tree, but I dont know how to do this.

Any help or advises is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: ¬ being the root node, second ¬ being the only child of the above node, "a" being the only child of the second ¬

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite rules can follow each alternative for your parser rule.

```
rule :
   alt1 -> rewriteRule1
 | alt2 -> rewriteRule2
 ...
 | altN -> rewriteRuleN;
```

You'll find that even after your parser grammar is working, you may need to restructure it to generate the correct tree. To address your specific problem, I suggest the following:

```
negationExpr :
   NEGATION negationExpr 
     -> ^(NEGATION negationExpr)
 | atom 
     -> atom;
```

This will add a level in the tree for each negation operator. The ^ will create a root for the token immediately following the parentheses and add the result of the next negationExpr rule as the child.

Comment: hi Adam12, you solution works beautifully. Thanks for your help, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Adam12's suggestion is an elegant solution. I just have one remark about your (JiandongC) code snippet, and another possible way to construct the AST.

Note that the `..` (range operator) is invalid inside parser rules! You'll need to make atom a lexer rule, or do:

```
atom 
  :  LETTER
  ; 

LETTER 
  :  'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z'
  ;
```

As to the creation of the AST, you *could* also let an even number of `NEGATION` tokens simply be ignored because `- -` will be positive.

```
negationExpr 
  :  (NEGATION NEGATION)* ( NEGATION atom -> ^(NEGATION atom)
                          | atom          -> atom
                          )
  ;
```

the rule above simply constructs `^(NEGATION atom)` if there are an uneven number of `NEGATION` tokens, else `atom` will be created as a single node (root).

Comment: Hi Bart Klert, when I post the question, I have ".." in atom grammer just to make it looks easier. I alrady have it what you suggested. But well done to point it out.

Comment: @JiandongC, yeah, I thought so, but wanted to be sure :). And people who read your post might think it's valid and try it "as is".

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion regarding ingoring even number of NEGATION tokens, it is a great suggestion, and I will think about it!

Comment: @JiandongC, no problem. There are things to be said to keep the AST as the original source, and at a later time optimize (a copy of) the AST by removing the `- -` and replace a tree like `^(* 0 ^(+ 1 ^(2 / 3)))` with `0` since `0 * ...` will always be zero anyway, etc. You decide when such things should be done.